# Cannot acces variable from angular provider inside angular config

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to angular, so I'm pretty sure it is a stupid question, but I failed to figure this out myself.
I have an app in which I have provider to get token from cookies using ngCookies, and I need to access it from inside app.config. I've tried several methods, but all I can get is service code, not a returned variable. What am I doing wrong?

```
var app = angular.module('appClient', [
  'ngCookies'
]);

app.provider('getToken', function getTokenProvider() {
  this.$get = ['getTokenService', function(getTokenService, $cookies) {
    var token = $cookies.get('token');
    return token;
  }]
});

app.config(function ($resourceProvider, $httpProvider, getTokenProvider) {
  var token = ? //need to get token from getTokenProvider here
  $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = false;
  $resourceProvider.defaults.actions = {
    save: { method: 'POST', params: { token: token } },
    get: { params: { token: token } },
    query: { params: { token: token }, isArray: true }    
  };
});
```

Comment: are you getting an error saying can not inject getTokenProvider?

Comment: No, getTokenProvider is injected just fine.

Comment: why do you need to have a token `getToken` provider sorry ?
you can already use the `var token = $cookie.get('token')` at your config already

Comment: @I.Black so you have tried `getTokenProvider.$get().token` and it does not work?

Comment: @MMhunter yeah, doesn't work.

Comment: @kiro112 I can't use it like this. I can inject cookies as in answer below, but I still would like to do it from provider if possible because I'll need to reuse it in several places

Comment: @I.Black btw.. what is the `getTokenService`? Did u define it somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a tricky solution based on your code. Anyone tell me if this has any side effects or drawbacks.

```
app.provider('getToken', function getTokenProvider() {

        this.$get = ['$cookies', function($cookies) {
         //$cookies.put("token","test");
        var token = $cookies.get('token');
        return token;
        }]

    });

    app.config(function (getTokenProvider,$injectorProvider) {
      //instantiate or get the service here
      //this should be how angular gets services
      //$injectorProvider.$get returns the instance injector (the $injector service)
      var token = $injectorProvider.$get().get("getToken");
      console.log(token);

    });
```

Here is the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/esAayeQll5ybBvWZHw9t?p=preview)

UPDATE:

Using this may cause problem when the there is any code changing the provider of depended services used to instantiate 'getToken'. For example, if you have `module.decorate` for `ngCookies` after this config block, it will fail to work.

Comment: That's actually exactly what I need, but for some reason I get Error: [$injector:modulerr] while using $injectorProvider (unknown provider), even though I basically run everything exactly like this. Any idea why? @MMhunter

Comment: Actually I have this error even when I copy-paste code from plunker, which is strange

Comment: Hmm I just make a check. The code above only works with angular 1.5.x. Older versions didn't expose the $injector service

Comment: Yes, that was it. Updated angular, now it works. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
  return {
    token: token
 };
```

add this line to return statement in provider and use

```
getTokenProvider.token
```

in controller

Comment: Doesn't work in config (getTokenProvider.token is undefined)